# If I have no certificate on my server, then why does HttpsUrlConnection connect?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, tls1.2

I've just worked out how to install a Lets Encrypt certificate on my server, so my browsers now show my site to be secure when I access via `https://`.

When I try to access my server end points in a Java client application using the following,

```
        URL httpsURL = new URL(urlStringServerEndPoint);
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        conn  = (HttpsURLConnection) httpsURL.openConnection();
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
        osw.write(dataString);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        os.close();
        conn.connect();

        if(conn.getResponseCode() != 200)
            throw new MyServerException();
```

this also works.

But - if I remove the certificate from my server and run the Java client again it still works. Surely it should throw up an error saying there's no certificate shouldn't it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did it work under https before you added the cert in the first place?

Comment: do you remove the certificate and restart the server?

Comment: @notyou Yes it did.

Comment: What kind of server and how did you 'remove the certiifcate'? Most webservers keep the cert&key in memory while running, and different LetsEncrypt clients (notably but I believe not only certbot) keep the key&cert in several different places. Try connecting with `openssl s_client -connect host:port [-servername host] -showcerts` (optionally using `openssl x509` to expand the results) or `keytool -printcert -sslserver host[:port]` to see exactly what cert(s) if any your server is providing.

Comment: @Victor I didn't restart it no. Didn't know I had to...

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I use ifastnet if that helps. I removed the certificate via "uninstall certificate" in the cPanel. Total newb at SSL. Only started looking into this and got it "working" today, except for this problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 when I run the `keytool` command line it shows up a bunch of stuff which mentions Lets Encrypt, so maybe although I've uninstalled the certificate I need to reboot the server.

Comment: @Antinous where i work we used to use Lets Encrypt in a proxy server (using `haproxy` as proxy application) and every time we touch something regarding domains and certificates we must restart haproxy in order to make all work fine.

Comment: thanks @Victor . For some reason now the certificate is gone and my Java client is giving a handshake error, so that's good. But I've just reinstalled the certificate and the Java client is still giving a handshake error. Nightmare.

Comment: I think maybe when I add/remove certificates I need to give my server a few minutes to do its stuff.

Comment: @Antinous i believe that configuring lest encript can give you several headaches... the server documentation (i guess a tomcat, if you are running a java web app) should be in handy... or not :P. Hope you find a solution to this without strugging to much!